How is value position calculated per player in hackenbush?
I am reading Winning Ways for your Mathematical Plays, and I'm having quite a hard time understanding how this position is equivalent to $\{9|10\}$
I understand (somewhat) the logic behind Left's value of 9, as they demonstrate it as being the best possible value left after Left (the bolded player) moves. However, how does the right player not have a score of -10, given that the game is balanced against them? Furthermore, what is my understanding of the score per player (the best possible value for that player after they make a move in the game state)?

Numbers do not represent the score of the player moving towards it. They represent left's score. So right moving towards $10$ gives them a negative outlook on winning the game, even though the number itself is positive.

Alright! So the number itself is the maximization of left's score for left and the minimization of left's score for right in one move on the current game state?

As long as all options for both players are numbers, that is correct. Otherwise, things become more complicated.

By the way, feel free to turn this into an answer!

Seems fair. Solving this little misconception was basically your question. Thanks for the suggestion!

As requested by LeoDog896, my comment formulated as an answer:
Numbers do not represent the score of the player moving towards it. They represent left's score. So right moving towards 10 gives them a negative outlook on winning the game, even though the number itself is positive.
